# p.adjust giving unexpected results

Tags: r, p-value

I'm trying to get adjusted p-values for a list of p-values, but the `p.adjust` function is giving me unexpected values.

```
CRISPR_gene_BH <- with(CRISPR_gene, data.frame(Transcript_Cluster_ID, Gene_Symbol, Fold_Change, ANOVA_p.value,
                                           Adjusted_p.value = p.adjust(CRISPR_gene$ANOVA_p.value, method = "BH"))

> head(CRISPR_gene_BH)
  Transcript_Cluster_ID Gene_Symbol Fold_Change ANOVA_p.value Adjusted_p.value
1              16845410        ETV4       14.44      8.06e-07       0.02385276
2              17055354        ETV1        4.89      9.20e-05       0.99969993
3              17065367   FAM90A20P       -1.11      1.08e-04       0.99969993
4              16962380        ETV5        4.89      1.93e-04       0.99969993
5              16817824      CORO1A        1.29      2.10e-04       0.99969993
6              16912114    RNU1-23P       -1.42      2.85e-04       0.99969993
```

The exact same commands on a separate data set (with an identical number of probes, i.e. rows), give me this:

```
> tail(ZFN_hits)
    Transcript_Cluster_ID Gene_Symbol Fold_Change ANOVA_p.value Adjusted_p.value
546              16890067       CREB1       -1.39      0.001823       0.09868273
547              16913095      CEP250       -1.13      0.001824       0.09868273
548              16891152     ZFAND2B       -1.13      0.001828       0.09871867
549              16914791       SNAI1        1.22      0.001833       0.09880838
550              16979024       PITX2       -1.18      0.001837       0.09884396
551              16872760         ERF       -1.33      0.001850       0.09936279
```

I used `tail` to show that, in this case, higher p-values have lower adjusted p-values compared to above, even though the two datasets are of equal length. Also, in case it matters (I've been reading conflicting reports), the p-values were already sorted in `CRISPR_gene`. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Am I just not grasping how the BH adjustment really works, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Veronique

Comment: have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323817/r-unexpected-results-from-p-adjust-fdr

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really help me. I have hundreds of probes with an adjusted p-value of 0.9996..., which means that at least some were originally higher than that, and they were all set to that value. Since I'm expecting them to be lower (not higher), it doesn't really answer my question.