# How Does R Calculate the False Discovery Rate

Tags: r, fdr

I appear to be getting inconsistent results when I use R's p.adjust function to calculate the False Discovery Rate. Based upon the paper cited in the [documentation](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~doerge/BIOINFORM.D/FALL06/Benjamini%20and%20Y%20FDR.pdf) 
the adjusted p value should be calculated like this:

```
adjusted_p_at_index_i= p_at_index_i*(total_number_of_tests/i).
```

Now when I run `p.adjust(c(0.0001, 0.0004, 0.0019),"fdr")` I get the expected results of

```
c(0.0003, 0.0006, 0.0019)
```

but when I run `p.adjust(c(0.517479039, 0.003657195, 0.006080152),"fdr")` I get this

```
c(0.517479039, 0.009120228, 0.009120228)
```

Instead of the result I calculate:

```
c(0.517479039, 0.010971585, 0.009120228)
```

What is R doing to the data that can account for both of these results?

Comment: I think this is the better question but it is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323817/r-unexpected-results-from-p-adjust-fdr/10327132

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that the FDR calculation ensures that FDR never increases as the p-value decreases. That's because you can always choose to set a higher threshold for your rejection rule if that higher threshold will get you a lower FDR.

In your case, your second hypothesis had a p-value of `0.0006` and an FDR of `0.010971585`, but the third hypothesis had a larger p-value and a smaller FDR. If you can achieve an FDR of `0.009120228` by setting your p-value threshold to `0.0019`, there is never a reason to set a lower threshold just to get a higher FDR.

You can see this in the code by typing `p.adjust`:

```
...
}, BH = {
    i <- lp:1L
    o <- order(p, decreasing = TRUE)
    ro <- order(o)
    pmin(1, cummin(n/i * p[o]))[ro]
```

The `cummin` function takes the cumulative minimum of the vector, going backwards in the order of `p`.

You can see this in the [Benjamini-Hochberg paper](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Edoerge/BIOINFORM.D/FALL06/Benjamini%20and%20Y%20FDR.pdf) you link to, including in the definition of the procedure on page 293, which states (emphasis mine):

> let k **be the largest i for which** P(i) <= i / m q*;
>
> then reject all H_(i) i = 1, 2, ..., k